# TFS: Need to populate "Found in" control (i.e. Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn) with builds from other project

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Under TFS 2010, I need to populate the "Found in" control on the Bug WITT etc. (i.e. Microsoft.VSTS.Build.FoundIn) with build info from other projects.

We've got a setup where all source is under one project and as we do devs we open up a new project/do some work/then close the project when it's finished; thus our bugs need to reference builds in the project that 'owns' the source code, however we only get presented with builds that are in the same project, any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: It's something to do with how "Suggested values" is set up, see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsprocess/thread/60f3e651-066b-4715-8dec-fe57ed6a94fd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done...
It looks like when a project's build 'fails and raises a bug' (i.e. not passes or quietly fails?) the collection's global list of builds for that project is updated, to get at that global list you add it as a suggested value for the control that's in the other project